# Wordpress Custom Post Type not showing in admin menu (created with CPT UI)

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type

I created a Custom Post Type using `CPT UI Plugin` called `program` and added contents to Custom Post Type which I created. Suddenly that menu item is not showing in admin menu (so far it showed in admin menu and I have already added posts to it).

**Note:** Previously added Custom Posts showing in Front-End and working fine. How can I get to display this Custom Post in Admin Menu ? I tried using changing the host and still the same thing happening.

[image]

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can you share the screenshot of same custom post type settings ?

Comment: @AkshayShah I have attached the screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue which I struggled so far.

In CPT UI plugin there is a setting called `show_in_menu`. That should be `true` to show the created custom post type in admin menu.